# mysql потребление памяти

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Дистрбутив Kubuntu 16.04 с последними обновлениями.
Ситуация такова: на десктопе запущен apache и mysql для разработки. Периодически программа на C++ обращается к mysql данным. В основном запросы select и их немного. Apache  держится для тестирования веб части и phpmyadmin. Стоит 4гб ОЗУ, x84. 4 основных базы данных с минимальными полями и таблицами. Однако mysql во время простоя ест от 500мб до 1гб оперативной памяти. Как можно уменьшить это потребление? my.conf стандартный, привожу его:

```
    #
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Вывод:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/mysql/conf.d
mysql.cnf  mysqldump.cnf
$ sudo ls /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
mysqld.cnf  mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
```

Писать все остальное откровенно лень, если понадобится - пишите.

Comment: Нужно содержимое только /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: по вашей ссылки файла просто не существует. Вот то что возможно вам надо. http://pastebin.com/HskJM1Zq

Comment: Таблицы какого типа преимущественно используете? MyISAM, InnoDB?

Comment: И те. и другие. На таблице в 3тыс записей(самая большая таблица во всех бд) - InnoDB

Comment: Как определяете занимаемый размер - это точно физическая память, а не виртуальная?

Comment: Стандартный системный монитор KDE. Да, это точно физическая память.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это был баг https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1576930 .
Помогло следующее решение:
Прописать в конфиг эти строки

```
innodb-read-io-threads=1
innodb-write-io-threads=1
```

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурационных файлах не видно, чтобы было выделено слишком много памяти на постоянные буферы или кэши.

128Мб должен потреблять буффер InnoDB, размер которого регулируется директивой `innodb_buffer_pool_size` в секции [mysqld]. Этот объем используется для кэширования данных и ключей InnoDB, можно попробовать его уменьшить, но слишком маленький объем может замедлить работу с InnoDB.

16Мб уходит на буффер ключей MyISAM `key_buffer_size`, не стоит делать его меньше - значение и так не велико.

16Мб уходит на кэш запросов `query_cache_size`. В принципе можно отключить этот тип кэша, локально вряд ли вы сможете извлечь из него пользу, тем более, если MySQL у вас часто простаивает.

Собственно все, какое-то количество памяти занимают другие кэши, но они настолько не велики, что вряд ли в сумме дадут несколько мегабайт.

Теоретически всю остальную память должны потреблять соединения (на каждое соединение может выделяться до нескольких мегабайт). Посмотрите, не висят ли соединения при помощи команды

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Если там слишком много соединений, снимите их при помощи оператора `KILL`.

Comment: 2 активных соединения 1 от phpmyadmin другой от root(я). Сначало процесс потребляет около 150мб памяти. Через некоторое время после запуска словно по таймеру каждые 3 секунды добавляется от 7 до 20мб и так пока не достигнет больших значений.

Comment: @Gravit выполните пожалуйста запрос show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'; какой результат возвращается?

Comment: 150Мб вам как раз дают те буферы, которые я привел в ответе, странно, что размер растет дальше.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size  134217728

Comment: На данный момент процесс mysqld потребляет 694 732кб памяти. Пока не стал его убивать, вдруг понадобится выполнить какие то запросы.

Comment: Не нормально много для вашей ситуации. Можно было понять, если бы у вас соединений 50-100 висело, текущие соединения, конечно трогать не стоит. Посмотрите еще show status like '%binlog%'; - может бинарные журналы включены.

Comment: Binlog_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_cache_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use  0
Com_binlog  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs  0